# Missed first blocks

Tags: block

I should have endorsed my first blocks about 30 minutes ago and its showing that I missed them, my node is synchronized, my endorser is running. Where do I start with troubleshooting?

Comment: you should go more into details of what setup you use to bake, such are you using kiln? just the binaries?

Answer (score -1):

I think I've found the problem, I was running the endorse with the older version, tezos-endorser-005-PsBabyM1. When I run this command I get a message saying nod syncronised but that was all, now when I run with tezos-endorser-006-PsCARTHA I get endorser started.

Comment: Answers are for answers to the original question. You should ask your follow up question in a different question, not in your answer. Also you might want to mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please ask your new question as separate question and then mark your own answer as accepted answer. Then i will remove my downvote. Thanks!